# deleteing data from database throw form action delete

Tags: php, html

if(isset($_POST['delete']))
    {
         $delete="DELETE * FROM project WHERE project_name=`project_name`";
             $projectdelete_res =  mysql_query($delete);
             $projectdelete_userRow= mysql_fetch_array($projectdelete_res);
     }
      ">

Comment: Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Oh @Narendra Soni ! What is this question dude. Why are trying to fetching from the resource# ? Its a perfect dumb question & code

Answer (score -1):

Use query as:

```
DELETE FROM project WHERE project_name='project_name'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I mean to say, remove * from your query.. In your query there is *